# Laravel default email verification layout?

Tags: laravel, email, verification

How can I change Laravel default email verification layout

[image]

Comment: go to resources > views >auth > passwords > email.blade.php

Answer (score 5):

### Email layout

You can use this artisan command to publish the vendor email templates (the layout of the emails):

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

A copy of the email templates will now be located in `resources/views/vendor/mail` and can be customized by you.

Laravel will use these published templates instead of the ones from the Laravel framework vendor code.

---

References:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#view-data

Comment: The OP asked for customizing the email template itself, not the view templates. The views that you're mentioning are the pages (views) that the user sees, not the email itself.

Comment: You are right, I had a bug in the absolute path. I have deleted that section now. The remaining explanation shows how to publish and find email templates (not views).

Answer (score 5):

This verification email has several parts which are found in different locations.
The email's subject and message can be changed here `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail.php`. Look for this function

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);

    if (static::$toMailCallback) {
        return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $verificationUrl);
    }

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'))
        ->line(Lang::get('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
        ->action(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'), $verificationUrl)
        ->line(Lang::get('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
}
```

The email template is here `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\resources\views\email.blade.php`

The views and other styling information including the css can be found here `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\resources\views\`

Comment: You should not modify vendor files.
With artisan, you can use the `vendor:publish` command to obtain an editable copy outside of the vendor folder.
Vendor files should not be modified because they depend on third parties that can be updated and thus introduce breaking changes. Moreover, those are typically not code versionned since vendor files can take up some hard drive real estate, and your modifications would not reach other people working on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Layout for verification email is located in `resources/views/auth/verify.blade.php`. You can change it there directly.

If you want to use completely different view for your verification, you can override the `show()` method inside the `VerificationController`. All you need to do is add this method on top of that controller:

```
public function show(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()
                        ? redirect($this->redirectPath())
                        : view('your.view');
    }
```

Comment: You can add publish all pages by running commands                                                          
 php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications

Comment: The OP asked for customizing the email template itself, not the view templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish view files by running this command

```sh
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

Then edit blade file in `resources/views/vendor/notification`

For more information about customizing email template visit this link
[How to Customize the Templates](https://laraveldaily.com/mail-notifications-customize-templates/)

Comment: The OP asked for customizing the email template itself, not the view templates.

Answer (score 0):

you should run this

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

Comment: You should explain why.

Comment: This publishes the generic template used for all emails and doesn't answer the OPs question: how to customize the email verification template.